# why is this program going through the while loop first and then the for loop?

Tags: tkinter, python-3.7

I have a tkinter program and I am trying to remove everything from the screen which I have done by putting everything in a list and then iterating through using `grid_forget()`. This works but I then have a timer after it which puts everything back on the screen. For some reasons it goes through the timer first and then clears the screen which is pointless as it immediately puts everything back. This is the section of code:

```
    items = [rollingFrame, savingFrame, score_frame, rerollButton, logoLabel, remainingRolls]
    for item in items:
        item.grid_forget()

    turnLabel = Label(root, text="turn {}".format(turn, 0), bg="lime green", anchor="center")
    turnLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=300, padx=500)
    

    previousTime = time.time()
    while (time.time() - previousTime) < 3:
        print(time.time()-previousTime)

    turnLabel.grid_forget()
```

Comment: The while loop blocks the tkinter from updating.  Add `turnLabel.update()` before the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the answer to your question, but this is a better practice that avoids the issue.

If you want to do something after a specified time in Tkinter use the after method.

```py
def my_function():
    turnLabel.grid_forget()

root.after(3000, my_function)
```

The first parameter is the time in milliseconds.
It is very common to need to do things like this for example if you need to run a function until a variable changes you can have the function call itself.

```py
forget = False

def my_function():
    global forget
    if forget:
        turnLabel.grid_forget()
    else:
        root.after(3000, my_function)

root.after(3000, my_function)
```

This code will run the my_function code about every 3 seconds until the variable `forget` is set to a `True` value.
I didn't run this code so my apologies if there are any syntax issues.